# How to use mongoimport for specific fileds from tsv file?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a .tsv file as follows,

```
Name   City   Mobile   Country
A      Hyd    877777   IN
B      Ban    78899    IN
```

Now, i don't want all the fields to be stored. I need some specific fields. I want import only Name, City and Mobile fields to Mongo DB using mongoimport.
I used the below command, but its not working

```
mongoimport --db test --collection persons  --type tsv --file persons.tsv --fields Name,City,Mobile
```

Final document stored in Mongo DB as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55accf948c59222984066646"),
    "Name" : "A",
    "Ciry" : "Hyd",
    "Mobile" : "87777"
}
```

Could you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible as using `mongoimport` you can only import whole file containing data in the database and not specific contents of a file.

To import your tsv file into the database as given above you can use:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection persons  --type tsv --file persons.tsv --headerline
```

**Explaination**

> `--headerline`
>
> If using --type csv or --type tsv, uses the first line as field names.
>   Otherwise, mongoimport will import the first line as a distinct document.
>
> If you attempt to include --headerline when importing JSON data,
>   mongoimport will return an error. --headerline is only for csv or tsv
>   imports.

If your tsv file only contains the data to be imported and not the field names as the header , you can use the `fields` property in `mongoimport`

example : `mongoimport --db test --collection persons  --type tsv --file persons.tsv --fields Name,City,Mobile,Country`

**Explaination**:

> `--fields <field1[,field2]>, -f <field1[,field2]>`
>
> Specify a comma separated list of field names when importing csv or
>   tsv files that do not have field names in the first (i.e. header) line
>   of the file.
>
> If you attempt to include --fields when importing JSON data,
>   mongoimport will return an error. --fields is only for csv or tsv
>   imports.

Comment: I am not using --headerline, i am using --fields only.. still it is not working

Comment: I am saying you have to use --headerline ,else it will treat the first line as a distinct document and not as a field header.

Comment: If i use --headerline , it will store all the fields in the Mongo DB, i don't want all the fields to be stored. I need some specific fields. If possible, could you please share the command?

Comment: I m so sorry that I misunderstood the question. According to my understanding the question you are asking is not possible as there are four fields in the tsv file and you only want data of three fields. Updating the answer for convinience.

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoimport` utility does not have any feature for doing this kind of manipulation of your input like you want to do in itself. This is "by design" as there are other tools that can handle this for you.

Notably there is the "pipe" `|` operator which is supported in both Unix  variants and Windows command prompt shells to name a few. So `mongoimport` itself can read from "standard input" rather than a given `--file` from "piped" input from another process doing the filtering.

A simple "perl" example ( but follow the same in scripting of choice ):

```
perl -pe 'chomp($_); @p = split(/\t/,$_); pop(@p); $_ = join("\t",@p) . "\n";' < persons.tsv
```

That will "strip" the last field from your source `persons.tsv` so the output is:

```
Name    City    Mobile
A       Hyd     877777
B       Ban     78899
```

Then simply "combine" the statement with the "pipe" `|` in order to pass that "input" into `mongoimport`:

```
perl -pe 'chomp($_); @p = split(/\t/,$_); pop(@p); $_ = join("\t",@p) . "\n";' < persons.tsv | \
mongoimport --db test --collection persons --type tsv  --headerline --ignoreBlanks
```

Which hapily creates the data:

```js
2015-07-21T09:53:40.726+1000    connected to: localhost
2015-07-21T09:53:40.741+1000    imported 2 documents
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
> db.persons.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ad8a04ee3124750e1600e7"), "Name" : "A", "City" : "Hyd", "Mobile" : 877777 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ad8a04ee3124750e1600e8"), "Name" : "B", "City" : "Ban", "Mobile" : 78899 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoimport full example:

> mongoimport --port 7812 -u "turkeyUserAdmin" -p "Turkey@DB^&*"
>   --authenticationDatabase "admin" --db "USA" --collection B2B --type tsv --fields
>   Database_Individual_ID.string(),Name.string(),Company.string()
>   --columnsHaveTypes --file F:/JAYBk/Project/B2B/Data/USA_B2B_DATA.tsv